# Unable to transmit stream through OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: networking, openvpn, ipv6, video-streaming, netcat

We are trying to transmit a video-stream via netcat from a OpenVPN server to a client.

The server is a Raspberry Pi with Pidora running on it. The client is a Notebook with Ubuntu 12.04 and has a IPv6 connection.

### OpenVPN

The Notebook is able to connect to the PI.
By *pinging* the server/client, packages are transmitted.

### Netcat

The firewall is open for port 5001.

By running:

(On Ubuntu)

```
nc6 -l -p 5001
```

(On the Raspberry)

```
nc6 10.8.0.6 5001
```

We are able to transmit text messages. Sending files by running

(On Ubuntu)

```
nc6 -l -p 5001 > test.txt
```

(On the PI)

```
cat test.txt | nc6 10.8.0.6
```

also works for small text-files (Python skript).

If we try to send pictures (.jpeg) or 2sec videos (.h264) the targeting file stays empty.

---

We also tried the connection to different PCs (Windows, Fedora) and this worked properly by displaying the video-stream. But they were not in the same network as the Ubuntu machine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE:

By setting the MTU to 1390 like [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-mtu-maximum-transmission-unit-of-network-interface-in-ubuntu-linux.html) described, bigger packages could pass the tunnel and the video-stream worked.

Comment: Why is this tagged ipv6? There doesn't seem to be anything relevant to IPv6 here.

Comment: So it's because we connect from a IPv4 network to a IPv6 network and this maybe is some critical point. But I am not shure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may well be an MTU issue.  Try [MTU clamping](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html) or [playing with mssfix and fragment options in Openvpn](http://wandin.net/dotclear/index.php?post/2009/01/08/OpenVPN-MTU-Size).

Comment: We played again with the MTU and we could finally get it working. I wrote an update in my question.